# Como alterar o gerenciador de pacotes do Vue Cli

Tags: vue.js

Recentemente instalei o Vue Cli e na seleção de instalação selecionei o Yarn como gerenciador de pacotes. Acontece que notei que a maioria das bibliotecas que instalei usam o NPM então tentei criar um novo APP, mas por padrão, o Yarn vinha como gerenciador de pacotes instalados.

Como realizar tal mudança?

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a resposta no GitHub https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1300

Na sua pasta home, ou na pasta do usuário do Windows, na raiz, tem um arquivo .vuerc. Abrindo você encontra o seguinte:

{
"useTaobaoRegistry": false,
"packageManager": "yarn"
},

só trocar para "npm" e salvar.
No meu caso, eu iniciei a instalação de um novo app. Se alguém aí souber como trocar em um projeto já existente e quiser expandir a discussão, eu agradeço.